# Replace the word between two characters php

Tags: php, laravel

I want the word between characters

```
'@' ,'_'
```

Change to

```
 <a href="$word">$word</a>
```

Example :

```
@Ali_ is a good boy, I and @Jan_ love him
```

change to

```
<a href="/Profile/Ali">Ali</a> is a good boy, I and <a href="/Profile/Jan"> Jan</a> love him
```

Comment: You'll want to use a regex, unless you're able to use one character to encapsulate the word instead of two different ones, e.g. @word@, in which case you could just explode the string and piece it together surrounded by <a> tags.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your response

```
$string = 'ae @ali er @hassan sss';
$string = preg_replace("/@(.+?) /is", "<a href='Profile/$1'>$1</a>", $string);
echo($string);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Tried and tested:**

```
function replaceString($content = '') {

  preg_match_all('/@(.*?)_/', $content, $matches);

  if(is_array($matches[0])) {

    foreach($matches[0] as $key => $match) {

      $new = $match;
      $new = str_replace('@', '', $new);
      $new = str_replace('_', '', $new);
      $new = '<a href="/Profile/' . $new . '">' . $new . '</a>';

      $content = str_replace($match, $new, $content);

    }

  }

  return $content;

}
```

The output of the following:

```
$content = '@name1_ and this other @name2_';
$content = replaceString($content);

echo $content;
```

Will be:

```
<a href="/Profile/name1">name1</a> and this other <a href="/Profile/name2">name2</a>
```